# How can i fix the 'Web application could not be started' error in passenger_wsgi.py

Tags: python, django, server

I attempted to install Django and Python on my server, but encountered the following error.

> Error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django''

[image]

This is my **passenger_wsgi.py** file:

[image: p]

Django module is here:

[image: p]

I tried to reinstall all of the modules, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your conda environement called `docker` is activated. Does it also have django installed? You can check with `conda list`. I suppose it is not.